# Qt5: Derive QQuickWidget to get a widget

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qwidget

I try to embed this qml definition:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: mqldefinition
    color: "green"
    width: 100
    height: 100

    Text {
        id: text
        text: "This is a text!"
        font.pointSize: 14
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

within a Qt C++-widget:

*qmlwidget.h*

```
#include <QQuickWidget>

class QmlWidget
      : public QQuickWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QmlWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};
```

*qmlwidget.h*

```
#include "qmlwidget.h"

QmlWidget::QmlWidget(QWidget *parent)
   : QQuickWidget(parent)
{
    resize(100,100);
    setSource(QUrl("qrc:/definition.qml"));
}
```

This widget shall be shown within the MainWindow as partly shown here:
*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "qmlwidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto qmlWidget = new QmlWidget(this);
    qmlWidget->move(0,0);
}
```

But it is not shown :(

---

I found this in SO:

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqmlfile.qml"));
view->show();
```

but I would like to implement it as derived class :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to set the `QmlWidget` as `centralWidget`.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QmlWidget *qmlWidget = new QmlWidget;
    qmlWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    setCentralWidget(qmlWidget);
}
```

[image]

Another approach is to use layouts to handle the size of the widget.

Comment: Thanks so far. The problem is not the size. For me it is the absolute position. there are a lot of widgets to place at very specific positions. The question is: Why it is not shown in this example.

Comment: @Alex44 
That question depends on many things, for me it was always shown, that depends on many variables, for example have you used the correct path of the .qml? You could share your project or a similar one through github

Comment: Your example works fine as you say. I also used `QQuickView()` together with `QWidget::createWindowContainer`, which works as well. But looks not so nice. Sharing needs a bit time, because I write from my mobile :P

Comment: @Alex44 No problem, let me know when you share it. :)

Comment: Your hint leads me to the problem: I only need to resize the mainwindow :P. So simple. Many Thanks